# Probably a simple error for you guy, I am new to php

Tags: php, error-handling

This is my first post here, I feel very welcomed as people told me you guys are nice to help people with problems.
I am making a website for a festival at school, and I somehow got this error today:

**mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectsite\News.php on line 135**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['test'])){

}else{
    $_SESSION["test"]=0;
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<title>News</title>
</style>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA"> 
<a href="http://localhost/projectsite/index.php" ><img src="images/nl.png"/></a>
<a href="http://localhost/projectsite/homeenglish.php" ><img src="images/uk.png"/></a>
<body background="images/achtergrondje2.jpg" style=>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #494b4a;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #dadada;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    <img src="images/bannertje2.jpg"
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #dadada;
}

li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #e83d3d;
}
</style>

</head>
</head>
<body><font color="white"
</body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/projectsite/index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/projectsite/lineup.php">Line-up</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/projectsite/inschrijven.php">Inschrijven</a></li>  
  <li><a class="active" href="http://localhost/projectsite/news.php">Nieuws</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="http://localhost/projectsite/contact.php">Over ons</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="http://localhost/projectsite/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="http://localhost/projectsite/Loginmain.php">Login</a></li>

    <br>
</ul>
  <?php if ($_SESSION["test"] == 1)
  {
?><li style="float:right" ><a class="active" href="html.php">uitloggen</a></li><?php
?><li style="float:right" ><a href=''><?php echo "Welkom Back ". $_SESSION["username"] . "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"?></a></li><?php
  }else{
  }  
  ?>
</ul>
<div class="flex-container">
<form method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr><td><h2>Nieuwsitem Toevoegen</h2></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Title:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtTitle" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Plaats:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtPlaats" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Description:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtDescription"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnnews" value="Invoeren" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnnwesplaatsen1" value="plaatsen" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<?php
    require('connect.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['btnnews']))
    {
        $title = $_POST['txtTitle'];
    $Description = $_POST['txtDescription'];
        $plaatsID = $_POST['txtPlaats'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `nieuwsitems` (txtPlaats, txtTitle, txtDescription) VALUES ($plaatsID, '$title', '$Description')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection);
        if($result)
        {
            $smsg = "Succes";
        }else{
            $fmsg ="";
        }
    }
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['btnnwesplaatsen1']))
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM nieuwsitems WHERE PlaatsID= 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$titel = $row['Title'];
$item = $row['Description'];

echo "$titel".'<br>';
echo "$item".'<br><hr>';
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is connect.php

```
 <?php
 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 if (!$connection){
 die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
 }
 $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'projectfestival');
 if (!$select_db){
 die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
 }
```

Comment: Hello, add this on line 135 : $db as first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

replace in your code that line..

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Comment: anser is correct then make it correct click right mark